# How to add background color for a multiple series of data in Gantt Chart

Tags: c#, highcharts, gantt-chart

how to add background color for each series in highcharts [{edited image with paint}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLFaj.png)

Comment: Hi @Harvin Chandran, Could you describe more precisely what you want to achieve and in which environment you use Highcharts?

Answer (score 0):

[API reference for .NET Highcharts](http://dotnet.highcharts.com/Help/Highcharts/html/class_highsoft_1_1_web_1_1_mvc_1_1_charts_1_1_column_series.html#a6cc5527425d1836bdcd43f66069c11a3) :

```
Series = new List<Series>
{
    new ColumnSeries
    {
        Color = "rgba(22,22,22,22)",
```